# How do i fill in NULL values that follow a good value with that good value?

Tags: mysql, database, null

I am using the following code to pull values from a production database which will pull values from production_count at the start of each hour and put them in their own column for each machine_id.

```
SELECT machine_id, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 5 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '05:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 6 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '06:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 7 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '07:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 8 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '08:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 9 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '09:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 10 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '10:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 11 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '11:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 12 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '12:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 13 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '13:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 14 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '14:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 15 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '15:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 16 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '16:00',
       MIN(CASE WHEN HOUR(timestamp) = 17 THEN production_count ELSE NULL END) AS '17:00'
FROM production
WHERE HOUR(timestamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 17
GROUP BY machine_id;
```

the trouble is when the machines are switched off a NULL value is inserted.

`0   0   94   214   327   429   493   626   742   850   883   NULL   NULL`

How can I fill in those NULL values with the last good value like:

`0   0   94   214   327   429   493   626   742   850   883   883   883`

Comment: There is no "last" in the way you're querying here, each is its own thing. Can you handle this in the application layer?

Comment: You could try using runtime variables `@a:=MIN(...) AS '05:00', @b:=IFNULL(MIN(...), @a) AS '06:00', @c:=IFNULL(MIN(...), @b) AS '07:00', ` etc.  so each value defaults to the previous value if it is null.  You may need to initialise the variables first, however.

Comment: There's also no guarantee of the order in which MySQL will process the expressions, so you'll just have to experiment to see what works with your particular install